# Jenkins pipeline stage - loop over sub directories of target directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm wanting to iterate over the contents of a folder that will contain a bunch of subdirectories so that I can run shell commands on each one.

I'm just trying to prove I can access the contents of the directory, and have this so far:

```
stage('Publish Libs') {
    when {
        branch productionBranch
    }
    steps {
        echo "Publish Libs"
        dir('dist/libs') {
            def files = findFiles() 
            
            files.each{ f -> 
                if(f.directory) {
                    echo "This is directory: ${f.name} "
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But getting this error

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/al-magma/branches/master/builds/5/libs/o3-app-pipeline/vars/magmaPipeline.groovy: 178: Expected a step @ line 178, column 25.
                           def files = findFiles()
```

What's the correct syntax here please?

Comment: This looks like declarative DSL. If that is true, then your scripted pipeline syntax needs to be enclosed in a `script` block to move forward with either success or a new error.

Answer (score 1):

You code works great, thanks! Just needed to enclose it in a `script` block:

```
stage('Iterate directories') {
    steps {
        script {
            dir('mydir') {
                def files = findFiles() 
            
                files.each { f -> 
                    if (f.directory) {
                        echo "This is a directory: ${f.name}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```